# How to print absolute path of some file from c:\ root in perl?

Tags: windows, windows-10, path, perl

Having this perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Cwd qw[abs_path];
use autodie;
opendir C, "c:\\";
@ar = map { abs_path($_) } readdir(C) or die $!;
print $ar[0];
```

I am trying to print an absolute path of first file from `c:\`, but an error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $ar[0] in print at C:\Users\ppast\OneDrive\Plocha\b.pl line 5.
```

Does anyone know, what is wrong?

Comment: Check the success of `opendir`: `opendir C, "C:\\" or die $!;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [readdir](http://p3rl.org/readdir) returns the file names, not paths to them. You need to prefix the paths yourself:

```
my @ar = map { abs_path('C:\\' . $_) } readdir C;
```

You should also check the success of [opendir](http://p3rl.org/opendir):

```
opendir C, "C:\\" or die $!;
```

Comment: I am using `autodie` to check for opening the dir. Sorry, but didnt help

Comment: @Herdsman: Sorry, I had a typo in my code, please, try again.